# Livewire Event Causing Route Change Results in Nav Buttons Not Being Active

Tags: laravel, events, navigation, laravel-livewire

So I have this Laravel 9 project. In this view below you can see the navigation bar:

[image: Navigation sidebar with active button]

The menu above for the active link (Overview) styling (Tailwind) is active via the check below in the view for the component looking at the request information:

`@if(request()->is('dashboard/*/overview'))`

This works great as the url currently is

localhost/dashboard/{ID}/overview

When clicking the bottom nav link for the Dividends this fires a livewire event for this account as they don't have permissions to access the page. No navigation away from the page Overview is performed. This event is used to setup a popup when the user doesn't have access to a feature. (I have these in a few places)

The issue is that when one of these fires it sets the 'is' check value in the request to
`/livewire/message/{COMPONENT_NAME}`

This seems to be the expected behaviour of the livewire events. I attempted a similar check using the code below but the same result occurred as the data is still tied to the request.

`@if(request()->pathInfo == "dashboard/7/overview")`

If anyone knows of another way or a better way I could have the intended functionality so that the button keeps it's 'active' properties after a livewire event has ran, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Is there a reason you have the navbar in a Livewire component? If it's not in a Livewire component, the active state wouldn't change, because Blade by default isn't reactive.

Comment: and did you try using php artisan r:l , to check the actual route that Dividends is using?

Comment: it is a livewire component. Nothing is wrong with the navigation or routing. When the user doesn't have access to the 'Dividends' feature, they remain on the Overview page and the event shows a popup to say they don't have permission.

This scenario should keep the Overview link as an 'active' link aka. styling shown in the orig screenshot should remain. However, emitting a livewire event changes the name of the route when checking it to apply button styles so it doesn't know the page is still the overview

Comment: Basically need a way to maintain the route check even after a livewire event. 

e.g If on the overview page and a livewire event is triggered but you haven't navigated anywhere, my checks for which page I'm on (for navbar styling) fail because of the livewire event overwrite the route details

Comment: @robby11110 did you try: <p class="{{ (\Route::current()->uri == 'your/route')  ? 'active' : ''}}">Overview</p>.  Using  \Route::current()->uri, you will get the actual route, maybe using request()-> is the problem

Comment: if you are not sure what is the route, just use <p>{{ \Route::current()->uri }}</p>

Comment: @haruk1515 just tried that method but same result. When the page is first loaded, it works great but the issue is after the livewire event has been emitted. e.g. when the page first loaded, the uri was `dashboard/{portfolio}/overview` so the checks work there. Once livewire event is emitted (which doesn't navigate away from the page) that check suddenly shows `livewire/message/{name}` as these livewire events must write over the route details. Maybe an alternative to Route would be the solution but I am not aware of any

Comment: That change in URI is the same for `Route:current()->uri` and `request()->is` and request()->pathInfo`

Comment: do you use wire:click=""?

Comment: did you for example try to get the actual route on the component and then pass it to the view and make the check

Comment: public $currentUrl;

public function mount()
{
    $this->currentUrl = url()->current();
}  we declare it in mount, because when the pages loades, it will get the inital value of the url

Comment: @robby11110 and pass it to the view,  return view('your.view', ['current_url' => $this->currentUrl])->extends('parent_view')->section('your_section');  try it

Comment: Amazing! It seems so obvious in hindsight but using the mount function to get the route is exactly what I needed. I used `request()->route()->getName()' to check against route name instead of the full URL. This is maintained throughout the livewire events. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @robby11110 Glad to hear that, keep the good work going!